# CURL for async send queue emails too fast, duplicate sent

Tags: php, email, curl

I have a PHP script that save my outbox emails in a database, for send it in async mode with CURL method, calling this function `curl_process_email_queue`:

```
function curl_process_email_queue() {


  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, ROOTURL . "queue_emails/execute.php");
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

  // Timeout super fast once connected, so it goes into async.
  curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1 );

  return curl_exec( $c );

}
```

My `execute.php` is:

```
<?php
ob_end_clean();
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo('Email async');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Encoding: none");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Connection: close");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
if (session_id()) session_write_close();
// connection is closed at this point
// start actual processing here
send_queued_emails();
```

So `send_queued_emails` is a recursive function that get 1 email at time, send it, remove it from DB and call itself for recursive. Exit only when queue table is empty

```
function send_queued_emails() {

    $db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM email_queue_async LIMIT 1;";
        $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute();
        $ris = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e);
    }

    if ( !$ris || count($ris) == 0 )
        return;

    $id = $ris['ID'];

    //  DELETE

    try {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM email_queue_async WHERE ID = ?;";
        $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute(array($id));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e);
    }


    $email = $ris['Email'];

    $result_sent = send_email($email); // function to send with phpmailer

    $db->commit();

    // recursively call the function

    send_queued_emails();
};
```

The problem is that CURL is async and very fast, so if I have only 1 email to send from my queue table, it send **2 times** everytime! I tried add some sleep() but no success. Is there a way to unify the SELECT with DELETE? in this way I think I can succesfull fix my problem.

UPDATE: some usefull info:

curl_process_email_queue is called at every loading page in my web app. and at the end of the script to insert emails to send in database, So it execute 2 times very fast and first execution can't DELETE record before second execution starts:

```
function insert_email_into_queue($email) {

  try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO email_queue_async (Email) VALUE ($email)";
            $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
            $rs->execute();

            curl_process_email_queue();

            header("Location: ./index.php");

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e);
        }

}
```

generic index.php:

```
<?php

curl_process_email_queue();

// some script
// get html structure
//...
```

Comment: I see this is an older question, and don't know if it's still an issue for you, but "curl_process_email_queue is called at every loading page in my web app" stands out as the likely problem. That's crazy. If many people access your website at once then inevitably you will get multiple requests to process the queue. Transactions can't save you because the function will be able to fetch a record which is already being processed. Instead, have a single background process triggered by cron which processes the queue sequentially and reliably.

Comment: P.S. personally I wouldn't delete from the queue entirely when you've processed a message...instead, just do a "soft delete" - i.e. update a field in that row like "processed" and set it to true (or 1). Then you have an audit record of which emails were processed, should anyone question it, or you need to look for bugs.

Comment: Also... in the `insert_email_into_queue` you initiate the processing by calling `curl_process_email_queue()`, then immediately redirect to index.php, which calls the same function again. So even without the problem of multiple users, you've already managed to do the processing twice, very close together. There's a strong chance this will happen faster than the email can be sent and the row deleted. As I said, the web application should simply write the email job into the queue, and a separate background program should actually process and send the emails.

Comment: Also it would be safer to run the select query as `SELECT * FROM email_queue_async ORDER BY ID Desc LIMIT 1` so that if more rows have been inserted (before the previous one was deleted) you can at least guarantee that it gets the latest row. This slightly reduces the chance of duplication in some circumstances but doesn't remove it entirely - a background process is really the only way to ensure that.

Comment: @ADyson HI, yes after some tests, i delegate the queue to send to a indipendent cron to easy solve my problem.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you solved it already. Sorry for opening up an old question, I just thought it was interesting.